# Warnings in IOS 8.1 with openAL in the soundOAL.m?

Tags: ios, openal

I've opened an old game project in Xcode 6.1.1 (made with Xcode 5.x) started it in the simulator with the iPad Air simulator and discovered after compiling it lots of strange warnings in the `SoundOAL.m` in many lines of this file. They mostly say something like this:

```
"Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'ALuint *' (aka 'unsigned int *')"
```

I think I know what it means (ps: app works without problems), but I was wondering if anything has changed and needs to be changed by me. I tried to find something in the iOS 8 docs but I could not read anything. Maybe someone knows it better?

Answer (score 1):

They're warnings due to their now being 64 bit support. You *can* ignore them, but if you see any unexpected results you should look there.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS devices support 64-bit, `NSUInteger` is 64-bit. Your code is passing a pointer to an `NSUInteger` to a method that takes an `ALuint`, which is defined in `al.h` as being 32-bit:

```
/** unsigned 32-bit integer */
typedef unsigned int ALuint;
```

To remove the compiler warnings, change your `NSUInteger` variable types to `ALuint` or cast them where appropriate, eg:

```
alSourceStop((ALuint)sourceID);
```